# PhpStorm not showing code hints inside array_map

Tags: php, phpstorm, code-completion

I get no code hints for this code:

[image]

The PHPDoc for `get_indexes` I think is done properly and NetBeans seems to understand it and show hints properly:

```
/**
 *  Get Index
 * 
 * @global object $wpdb
 * @param String $extension_table_name
 * @return \ZRDN\Recipe[]
 */
public static function get_indexes($extension_table_name) {
    global $wpdb;
    $db_name = $wpdb->prefix . $extension_table_name;
    $selectStatement = "SELECT * FROM `{$db_name}`";
    $recipe_indexes = $wpdb->get_results($selectStatement);

    return $recipe_indexes;
}
```

`Recipe` is defined in the same file under same namespace:

```
class Recipe {
   /**
    * @var int
    */
   public $recipe_id;

   /**
    * @var int
    */
   public $post_id;
...
```

Any ideas what the issue might be?

Comment: PhpStorm does not seem to cover such usage case yet. Just typehint your `$recipe` manually with inline PHPDoc.

Comment: For reference purposes: same on JetBrains Forums: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000790250-Code-hinting-not-working- . In short: typehint manually (be it PHPDoc or PHP's native typehint). PhpStorm Feature ticket -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-18347

Comment: It makes no sense how NetBeans supports this but not PhpStorm. I considered switching but I've got debugging working in PhpStorm and don't want to go through the trouble.

Answer (score 8):

If you know that `$recipes` always contains objects of type `Recipe` then use it as the type of the `$recipe` argument of the map function:

```
$post_ids = array_map(function(Recipe $recipe) {
    return $recipe->recipe_id;
}, $recipes);
```

This way PhpStorm (and other IDEs) can help you with the autocomplete and also the PHP interpreter triggers a fatal error when it encounters a value in `$recipes` of the wrong type.